# Replicate an InnoDB table into a FEDERATED table

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, federated

I would like to have a new table with FEDERATED engine, created (cloned) from another existing InnoDB table. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE balance_live
  AS SELECT * FROM balance
  ENGINE=FEDERATED
  CONNECTION='mysql://user:pass@8.8.8.8:3306/db/balance'
```

But this doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an actual table definition, specified explicitly. It's not a view, it's a table. See here for the correct syntax:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE balance;` on the remote host and use that as the definition, just change `ENGINE=FEDERATED` and add the CONNECTION clause.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE balance;` was exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual on [creating federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create.html) says:

> Create the table on the local server with an identical table definition, but adding the connection information that links the local table to the remote table.

You cannot use the `as select ...` , since in the `from` clause you can only specify a local table. It is the federated table that creates the link to the remote table.

Just copy the table definition over from the remote table.